# Passing the members/variables from python script to a shell script or a command

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I am trying to use variables obtained from an xml file by a python script. Once the variables are obtained i would like to pass these to a command which runs by a shell script. need help with this

My Python script is something like the below

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
from hive import ThriftHive
filename = "mood_ib_history_parameters_DEV.xml"
__currentlocation__ = os.getcwd()
__fullpath__ = os.path.join(__currentlocation__,filename)

tree = etree.parse(__fullpath__)
root = tree.getroot()

hive_db = root.find("hive_db").text
EDGE_HIVE_CONN = root.find("EDGE_HIVE_CONN").text
target_dir = root.find("target_dir").text
to_email_alias = root.find("to_email_alias").text
to_email_cc = root.find("to_email_cc").text
from_email_alias = root.find("from_email_alias").text
dburl = root.find("dburl").text
SQOOP_EDGE_CONN = root.find("SQOOP_EDGE_CONN").text
user_name = root.find("user_name").text
password = root.find("password").text
IB_log_table = root.find("IB_log_table").text
SR_DG_master_table = root.find("SR_DG_master_table").text
SR_DG_table = root.find("SR_DG_table").text

print hive_db
print EDGE_HIVE_CONN
print target_dir
print to_email_alias
print to_email_cc
print from_email_alias
print dburl
print SQOOP_EDGE_CONN
print user_name
print password
print IB_log_table
print SR_DG_master_table
print SR_DG_table
```

The variables will be

- hive_db
- EDGE_HIVE_CONN
- target_dir
- to_email_alias
- to_email_cc
- from_email_alias
- dburl
- SQOOP_EDGE_CONN
- user_name
- password
- IB_log_table
- SR_DG_master_table
- SR_DG_table

The shell command which is going to be run in a shell script is as below

```
ssh -i /apps/phodisvc/.ssh/id_rsa_edge_node ${SQOOP_EDGE_CONN} "sqoop import -D mapred.child.java.opts='\-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/../dev/urandom' --connect '${dburl}' --username ${user_name} --password ${password} --query \"select CONTRACT_ID,CONTRACT_NUMBER,CONTRACT_STS_CODE,CONTRACT_STATUS,SERVICE_LINE_ID from XXCCS where \\\$CONDITIONS \" --split-by CONTRACT_NUMBER -m 4 --null-string '\\\\N' --null-non-string '\\\\N' --hive-delims-replacement '<EOL>' --boundary-query 'select (select min(CONTRACT_NUMBER) from XXCCS_DS_SAHDR_CORE) as minid ,(select max(CONTRACT_NUMBER) from XXCCS_DS_SAHDR_CORE) as maxid from dual' --target-dir ${target_dir}/XXCCS_DS_SAHDR_CORE --hive-import --hive-overwrite --hive-table ${hive_db}.XXCCS --map-column-hive CONTRACT_ID=BIGINT,SERVICE_LINE_ID=BIGINT"
```

I do not want to use call() or subprocess() methods withing the first script as i want to divide the tasks into modules. Need help.

Comment: Whatever means you use to execute the shell command, all the variables must be available to the code together at that point. So even if you divide the task into subroutines, you can return the variables from them. But if the variables are not all known at some point in the code, there's no way of calling a shell function with those. (Your code cannot tell the shell what the code itself doesnt know)

Comment: Hi @VBB the variables always come from the first script and the second script executes only after successful execution of the second script.

Answer (score 0):

Once you know the variables, you just have to pass then to a command line in shell.

```
cmd = 'ssh -i /apps/phodisvc/.ssh/id_rsa_edge_node {0} "sqoop import -D mapred.child.java.opts='\-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/../dev/urandom' --connect '{1}' --username {2} --password {3} --query \"select CONTRACT_ID,CONTRACT_NUMBER,CONTRACT_STS_CODE,CONTRACT_STATUS,SERVICE_LINE_ID from XXCCS where \\\$CONDITIONS \" --split-by CONTRACT_NUMBER -m 4 --null-string '\\\\N' --null-non-string '\\\\N' --hive-delims-replacement '<EOL>' --boundary-query 'select (select min(CONTRACT_NUMBER) from XXCCS_DS_SAHDR_CORE) as minid ,(select max(CONTRACT_NUMBER) from XXCCS_DS_SAHDR_CORE) as maxid from dual' --target-dir ${target_dir}/XXCCS_DS_SAHDR_CORE --hive-import --hive-overwrite --hive-table ${hive_db}.XXCCS --map-column-hive CONTRACT_ID=BIGINT,SERVICE_LINE_ID=BIGINT"'.format(SQOOP_EDGE_CONN,user_name,password,...)

os.sytem(Cmd)
```

Doc's

[String formmatting operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting)
e
[Execute command in subshell](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system)